# removing a tuple in a list and then assigning average value to the removed tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

This is the list:

```
trandom= [(4, 1), (3, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1)]

for indx, tup in enumerate(trandom):
print("original list", trandom)
#remove the tuple that computes the average
removedfromList= trandom.pop(indx)
#updatedList=(trandom, average[indx])
print(trandom+[average[indx]])
updatedList=trandom+[average[indx]]
print(list(chain(*(i if isinstance(i, tuple) else (i,) for i in updatedList))))
break
```

Results into

```
 ('original list', [(4, 1), (3, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1)])
[(3, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1), 2.5]
```

Upto this point it's fine because I have been able to append average as the last element of the tuple.

My goal here now is to assign the average (0.5) in this case for the first tuple from original list (1,0) and flatten the the tuple into list then compute its average and standard deviation. I have to do this process randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion regarding what you are asking.

After fixing your syntax errors, your code outputs the following:

```
original list [(4, 1), (3, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
[(3, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1), 0.0]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0.0]
```

The following code gives you the output that you described:

```
trandom= [(4, 1), (3, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1)]

#remove for loop because you are breaking out of it after 1 iteration
print(("original list", trandom)) #make the output a tuple
updatedList=(trandom+[np.average([i[0] for i in trandom])])
removedfromList= updatedList.pop(0) #remove the first from updated
print (updatedList)
#next line was not in your output
#print(list(it.chain(*(i if isinstance(i, tuple) else (i,) for i in updatedList))))
```

In regards to your second part, I am not sure what you are looking for. (1,0) is certainly not the first element in the original list. Please clarify what you are trying to do.